# Оптимизация объединенного запроса UNION

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mariadb

mariadb. Имеется объединенный запрос:

```
SELECT id, name FROM t1 WHERE id>0 AND id<7
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM t1 WHERE id IN (10,12,15)
UNION
...
LIMIT 5;
```

Будут ли выполняться второй и последующие подзапросы, если в первом уже найдено 5 записей?
Есть ли возможность переписать запрос таким образом, чтобы второй и последующие подзапросы выполнялись только при необходимости (только в том случае, если первый подзапрос вернул меньше 5 записей)?

В моем случае приоритетными будут записи найденные в первом подзапросе. Если их недостаточно, то дополнить результат записями второго подзапроса и так далее.

Comment: А зачем объединять данные из одной таблицы, когда можно написать "WHERE id>0 AND id<7 AND id IN (10,12,15)"?

Comment: *Будут ли выполняться второй и последующие подзапросы, если в первом уже найдено 5 записей?* Да. *Есть ли возможность переписать запрос таким образом, чтобы второй и последующие подзапросы выполнялись только при необходимости* В формате запроса - можно, но будет ещё медленнее. Ускорить можно только использованием хранимой процедуры. PS. Показанный запрос не обязан вернуть записи именно из первого подзапроса.

Comment: @Akina, в хранимой процедуре выполнить первый подзапрос, сравнить возвращаемое количество записей с 5, и исходя из этого выполнять второй подзапрос?

Comment: Интересно, а если сделать что-то типа такого: `SELECT 1 as priority, id, name FROM t1 WHERE id>0 AND id<7 ... ORDER by priority LIMIT 5` не будет ли такой запрос сам нужным образом оптимизирован? Вернее, это тогда нужно наверное второй уровень `SELECT`-а делать для `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Это будет тот же UNION плюс дополнительная сортировка.

Comment: *в хранимой процедуре выполнить первый подзапрос, сравнить возвращаемое количество записей с 5, и исходя из этого выполнять второй подзапрос?* Именно так. Только выбранные записи - складывать во временную таблицу. А как наберётся нужное количество записей - так делать уже финальный SELECT в выходной поток.

Comment: спасибо. Я предполагал, что временные записи складывать нужно в переменную. Заносить их в во временную таблицу не будет медленнее? запрос этот будет выполняться очень часто - в 99.9% случаев при запросе страниц сайта.

Comment: Временные таблицы - отличная штука, они довольно быстрые.